# Google AdMob "we'll try not to show that ad again"

Tags: android, google-ads-api, admob

I'm using AdMob for displaying ads in my Android app.

I have integrated all the steps and I was getting the ads, but suddenly it started showing **"we'll try not to show that ad again"**. Why does this happen?

Comment: did you try it on devices other than test devices(addTestDevice)? seems it works there.

Comment: Don't know if it's relevant, but one of the apps I use every day that normally shows ads (I think it was Word Trek) suddenly (yesterday, I think) it started showing that message, and I'm pretty sure I never clicked any kind of "flag as inappropriate" option. (Today, it seems not to be showing any ads).

Comment: My apps have the same issue. It only happens start from 2nd Dec. and for native express ads. No problem to see banner, interstitial ads.

Comment: Google Ads Status [Dashboard](https://ads.google.com/status) is now showing some issue, not exactly this one though, and it's for other Ad product. But this can be related; wasn't showing earlier when this was just started. from the dashboard: > We're aware of a problem with DoubleClick for Publishers affecting a
> majority of users. The affected users are able to access DoubleClick
> for Publishers, but are seeing error messages and/or other unexpected
> behavior. We will provide an update by 12/2/16, 10:30 PM detailing
> when we expect to resolve the problem. Please note that this
> resoluti

Comment: The issue is now resolved by Google, we don't have to do anything! It is working as usual!

Comment: yes, started working normal now :)

Comment: It only worked for a few hours and now we can still see the same issue.

Comment: It was an admob issue, they have now fixed the bug and ads are back to the normal behaviour.