# NativeExpressAdView stopped showing ad. "We'll try not to show that ad again" message

Tags: android, firebase, admob

I'm using Google's `NativeExpressAdView` to show native ads. It used to work fine but since yesterday it shows "We'll try not to show that ad again" in place of the ad.

The ad exists as an item in a recyclerview. The view starts off gone, is loaded in `onBindViewHolder` and made visible `onAdLoaded` callback.

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:10.0.0'
```

Tried changing the library version back to 9.8 but same result.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40926729/google-admob-well-try-not-to-show-that-ad-again

Comment: I am also facing the same issue but sometime ads are coming. don't know whats went wrong.